# Item Templates vs Part Templates in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchardcms-1.7

I'm learning Orchard and I did some Pluralsight course. It covered Part Templates, but now I'm reading this article: [Anatomy of a theme](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Anatomy-of-a-theme) and there's a section called: **Item Templates**. And I'm confused. I think I haven't came across this notion before. What is the difference? Let's have a sample that I have a content type **Movie** with content part **Movie**. I can override how it's rendered using **Part Template**. So where I would use **Item Template** in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Wrote a blog post with a tiny bit more detail in regards to this question. Shameless plug: http://arkleseizure.net/what-the-hell-is-an-item-template**

The wording is not particularly clear I would agree. So let's see if we can clear this up a little...

Content Type: Movie

- TitlePart
- DirectorPart
- StudioPart

(So you have a content type called movie with 3 parts attached to it).

We want all the parts to be displayed in the detail view and only the TitlePart displayed in the Summary display. So we use placement.info

```
<Match ContentType="Movie">
  <Match DisplayType="Summary">
    <Place Parts_TitlePart="Summary:1" />
    <Place Parts_DirectorPart="-" />
    <Place Parts_StudioPart="-" />
  </Match>

  <Match DisplayType="Detail">
    <Place Parts_TitlePart="Content:1" />
    <Place Parts_DirectorPart="Movie:1" />
    <Place Parts_StudioPart="Movie:2" />
  </Match>
</Match>
```

(Explicit notation used for clarity)

Placement basically defines where your content parts will be placed for a content type. Summary, Content and Movie are "zones" within a content item that you assign parts to so they can be displayed. So let's go ahead and define our Content and Movie zones in a file called Content-Movie.Detail.cshtml (This would be an "Item Template").

```
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;

<article class="content-item">
  <div class="content">
    @Display(Model.Content)
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    @Display(Model.Movie)
  </div>
</article>
```

And one for summary, Content-Movie.Summary.cshtml

```
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;

<article class="content-item">
   <div class="content">
      @Display(Model.Summary)
   </div>
</article>
```

(You can use the shape tracing tool (http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools) to generate these for you and it will create default zones (Header, Meta, Content and Footer, I believe) and the relevant html.)

Our parts should now be displaying in the right places and we may want to change how the title is displayed. So we can create a "Part Template", Parts.Title.cshtml

```
<h1>Movie: @Model.Title </h1>
```

So in summary. **Content Types** are made up of lots of **Content Parts**. **Part Templates** override the Content Parts and **Item Templates** override the layout of a Content Type where **Zones** are defined. **Placement.info** direct Content Parts to the zones to be displayed.

Hope that helps!