# How do render shape of a specific ContentPart of a ContentItem from alternative razor file?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, orchardcms

Considering we have a simple `ContentType` named Product which has some fields and `ContentPart`s such `CommentPart`. When we create an alternative for `Product` (`mytheme/Views/Content-Product.Detail.cshtml`) then every fields and parts should be render from the alternative file. for example we can access to fields value and display theme.

But my question is that how to render default shape of the parts of the `ContentType` from our alternative file?

for example the Product has `CommentPart` and i want to call the default `Display` of it in a arbitrary place of view:

```
@using Orchard.Utility.Extensions;
@{
    if (Model.Title != null)
    {
        Layout.Title = Model.Title;
    }

    Model.Classes.Add("content-item");

    var contentTypeClassName = ((string)Model.ContentItem.ContentType).HtmlClassify();
    Model.Classes.Add(contentTypeClassName);

    var tag = Tag(Model, "article");


    var Title = Model.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title;
    var CreatedUtc = Model.ContentItem.CommonPart.CreatedUtc;
    var Path = Model.ContentItem.AutoroutePart.Path;
    var Thumb = Model.ContentItem.Product.ThumbnailImage.FileName;
    var Price = Model.ContentItem.Product.Price.Value;
    var CooperatorPrice = Model.ContentItem.Product.CooperatorPrice.Value;
    var Discount = Model.ContentItem.Product.Discount.Value;
    var Available = Model.ContentItem.Product.Available.Value ?? false;
    var Special = Model.ContentItem.Product.Special.Value ?? false;
}
@tag.StartElement
<a href="@Path" >
    @if (Special != null)
    {
        <img class="special" src="@Url.Content("Themes/RayanTechTheme/Content/Images/specialoffer.png")" />
    }
    @if (Thumb != null)
    {
        <img class="thumb" src="@Url.Content(Thumb)" />
    }
    <header>@Title</header>
    @if (Available != null)
    {
        <span class="available"></span>
    }
    @if (Price != null && Price > 0)
    {
        <span class="price">@RayanTechTheme.Helpers.CurrencyHelper.GetSeperatedCurrency(Price) تومان</span>
    }
    @if (Price != null && Price > 0 && Discount != null && Discount > 0)
    {
        <span class="prev-price">@RayanTechTheme.Helpers.CurrencyHelper.GetSeperatedCurrency(Price + Discount) تومان</span>
    }
    @if (CooperatorPrice != null && CooperatorPrice > 0)
    {
        <span class="cooperatorprice">@RayanTechTheme.Helpers.CurrencyHelper.GetSeperatedCurrency(CooperatorPrice) تومان</span>
    }
    @if (Discount != null && Discount > 0)
    {
        <span class="discount">@RayanTechTheme.Helpers.CurrencyHelper.GetSeperatedCurrency(Discount) تومان</span>
    }
    @if (CreatedUtc != null)
    {
        <span class="createdutc">@RayanTechTheme.Helpers.DateHelper.GetPersianDate(CreatedUtc)</span>
    }
    <div class="more">
         @Display.Parts_CommentForm(Model.ContentItem.CommentPart)  /// >>>>>  HOW DO IT???
    </div>
</a>
@tag.EndElement
```

How do i implement the last `<div>` as i mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is by using [Orchard's Placement](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Understanding-placement-info).

Rewrite your `<div>` to look like:

```html
<div class="more">
    @Display(Model.Comments)
</div>
```

Then in your Placement.info

```xml
<Match ContentType="MyContentType">
    <Match DisplayType="Detail">
        <Place Parts_CommentForm="Comments:1" />
    </Match>
</Match>
```

When your ContentItem Shape is being rendered, the Shapes for each of its parts are already built ready for display (I think, someone like [Bertrand Le Roy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/363821/bertrand-le-roy) could correct me on this if I'm wrong).

The `@Display()` helper is for rendering Shapes, which are created from a Part's Driver. The Placement.info tells Orchard where these Shapes should display.

---

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19388208/1053199

Comment: You might be interested in this technique: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2013/02/13/easy-content-templates-for-orchard-take-2.aspx

Comment: Thank you it worked me,i +1 voted you. But i don't understand what means the Parts_CommentForm="Comments:1" , when we call explicitly the view of the 'Comment' an our alternate! it means that the default of placement for Parts_CommentForm is '-' ! please tell me what is happening on placement and why the Display method should not work if we don't set placement info?

Comment: and in placement.info what is the defference between "Comments:1" and "Content:1" values?

Comment: If you set your Placement.info value to be 'Content:1' (the Zone), the Part will be placed where ever you've placed @Display(Model.Content) in your template. What we've done in my answer, is set a zone called 'Comments' by writing @Display(Model.Comments), and told Orchard to place the CommentForm Part in this zone. The ':1' is the order in which to place each part within the zone.

Comment: Have a good read of Betrand's blogpost above as it explains this scenario quite well.